# IE font-face fails to load when not using FQDN

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-face

I have a font-face defined in my CSS that looks like the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'iconFont';
  src: 
      url('../fonts/iconFont.eot?') format('eot'), 
      url('../fonts/iconFont.woff') format('woff'), 
      url('../fonts/iconFont.svg#iconFont') format('svg'), 
      url('../fonts/iconFont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I also have a few other font-faces of a similar format. When using the fully qualified domain name of my PC (eg 'mypc.mydomain.local') Internet Explorer 9+ retrieves the fonts and renders the page correctly. However, when using just the hostname of my laptop (eg 'mypc') IE never even attempts to retrieve the fonts. I have confirmed this using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).

The only difference I can see is that a different security zone is in effect depending on whether the fully qualified name is used (Internet) or just the hostname (Local intranet). Both of these zones have the "Download Fonts" set to enable on my PC.

If it is related to the security zone then it is surprising that the intranet settings seem to be allowing less than the internet settings. Or it's a bug in IE.

Firefox downloads the fonts and renders correctly regardless of the hostname I use.

Comment: What is you'r laptop IE version ?

Comment: Laptop is running IE 10 on Windows 8. Also occurs on IE 9 on XP.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer enforces a same-origin or CORS check on WOFF fonts. If you have a page at "mypc.mydomain.local", it can't use a font from "mypc" unless a proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present.

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/troubleshooting#CORS_header

Comment: I'm serving the fonts from the same site as the CSS. The font urls are relative so I would assume that the same server name would be used in the font urls. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What, if anything, do you see in IE's F12 Developer Tools' Console tab? How exactly does your HTML file refer to your CSS file? Is your page in IE Standards mode?

Comment: The following error: "CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable." is shown in the console. I've since changed back to using the googleusercontent urls rather than embedding them. This also indicates that the page is running in "Compatibility View" which I do not want. Still investigating this.